# Zookeeper for Kafka and Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I developed a project which reads messages from Kafka and process it in the Storm. However, I did not do anything about zookeeper except setting configuration to port:2181. Is there anything about Zookeeper to implement in my project or docker yaml file ? Maybe it should be run as ProcessBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka process requires Zookeeper configured. in `server.properties`

Storm also needs Zookeeper in `storm.yaml`

Kafka clients above, 0.9 do not require Zookeeper configurations. Any code within Storm topologies shouldn't need to explicitly be using Zookeeper without good reason.

If you're using Docker for each of these services, you'll need to link the containers and set some environment variables